# how can i pass a <br/> inside a string from expressjs to pug template

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have this code in express and i what to break a line in middle of text or put an image etc..

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  obj = { 
    text: `some text <br/> more text`
  };
  res.render('index', obj);
});
```

Imagine I fetch the info from a database and inside the information i have some html tags

what is the best approach in this case to perform the desire result (break a line).

On the .pug side i have this code:

```
p
  | #{obj.text}
```

The output is 'br' printed like text and not perform a break.

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To output unescaped variable value use `!{varname}` instead of `#{varname}`. In your case it should be:

```
p
  | !{obj.text}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, if the `obj.text` is the only value for the `p`

```
p!= obj.text
```

> **Unescaped buffered code can be dangerous.** You must be sure to sanitize any user inputs to avoid cross-site scripting (XSS).

https://pugjs.org/language/code.html